# How to undo changes of only particular git commit?

Tags: git

Suppose I'm doing changes in a file and I made 5 changes and committed after each change so there are 5 commits:

```
commit 5 <-Head
commit 4
commit 3
commit 2
commit 1
```

and I want to undo what commit 3rd changes but I want that the 4th and 5th commit changes remain in the file.

I know what `git revert <commit-hash>` does but it also undoes the changes made by recent commits (say commit 4th and 5th). It takes us back to the changes of commit 2nd by undoing the 3rd commit but in this case, we also lost changes made by commit 4th and 5th.

I want only that commit 3rd changes will be undone and the rest of the recent commits (4th and 5th) changes remain in the file.

Is this possible to do so?

**Edit:**

I'm getting a conflict to keep current changes or incoming changes and in incoming changes, it's removing the whole commit 4 & 5 changes along with commit 3 changes.

Comment: No, that's not right.  If you run `git revert commit-3`, it will take back the changes that were introduced in that revision _only_. Changes applied in commits 4 and 5 will remain there.

Comment: Another option is to use interactive `rebase` and `drop` the 3rd commit but go for `revert` if you don't care about an additional commit in the history, that's way easier

Comment: @eftshift0 that's not happening at my end. I'm getting a conflict to keep current changes or incoming changes and in incoming changes, it's removing the whole commit 4 & 5 changes along with commit 3 changes.

Comment: If you are getting a conflict, it's because commit 4 and/or 5 made a change to the same areas that commit 3 did, and it's not clear whether the final state should match commit 2 or commit 5. You are resolving the commit in a way that chooses commit 2, but that is by no means the *only* option.

Comment: Ok, that's a _different_ topic. If you have a conflict, you need to take care of it _correctly_. It's not like git is forcibly removing the changes from revisions 4 and 5. If you need help on _that_ topic, then you can take a look at http://www.ezconflict.com (my stuff, no monetization, no tracking, no cookies, etc).

Comment: Yes, changing the area does the job. Thank you so much! You saved a life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour was happening because I was making changes in the same area of a file.

Changing the area does the job as expected.